# Create a cookie for NSURLRequest?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to send an authentication string via cookie in a NSMutableURLRequest. I'm trying to create the NSHTTPCookie through

```
 +(id)cookieWithProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties
```

But nowhere have I been able to find how to specify the properties other than the simple key-value pair I have for authentication. When I only use my key-value pair, nil is returned.

Any examples, documentation, or thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to create the cookie; did you take a look at http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001702-425346

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how you set properties in a cookie:

```
 NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              url, NSHTTPCookieOriginURL,
                              @"testCookies", NSHTTPCookieName,
                              @"1", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                              nil];
  NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
```

In the example above:
 `url`, `testCookies`, and `1` are the **values**. Likewise, `NSHTTPCookieOriginURL`, `NSHTTPCookieName`, `NSHTTPCookieValue` are the **keys** for the `NSDictionary` object, *as in key-value pairs*.

You set/get properties using `NSDictionary` and add to `NSHTTPCookie`.

Comment: Actually i was not able to get it work, only with NSHTTPCookieDomain, and NSHTTPCookiePath. See jm's answer. Also: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Webkitsdk-dev/2003/Sep/msg00003.html

Comment: I was able to use NSHTTPCookieOriginURL as long as I *also* specified NSHTTPCookiePath (thanks to jm below for the hint). Note that you can use the path method on the url to provide the value (i.e. [url path]).

Answer (score 40):

I noticed on, on my 2.2.1 iPhone, that the cookie didn't get created if NSHTTPCookiePath is not specified, even though it is shown as "optional" in the docs:

So, I do:

```
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"example.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                            @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,  // IMPORTANT!
                            @"testCookies", NSHTTPCookieName,
                            @"1", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                            nil];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];

NSArray* cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];

NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```

Answer (score 7):

I could not get that to work.

I got this to work however:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* ret = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[ret setValue:@"myCookie=foobar" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

Answer (score 7):

I've found one mistake in jm's example: NSHTTPCookiePath should be `@"/"`, but not `@"\\\\"`.

```
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"example.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                            @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,  // IMPORTANT!
                            @"testCookies", NSHTTPCookieName,
                            @"1", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                            nil];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];

NSArray* cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];

NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Seems reasonable, although I don't have an iphone to test on anymore.

Answer (score 0):

key `NSHTTPCookiePath` should exist in dictionary when using

```
[NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:dictionary]
```

method whether using `NSHTTPCookieDomain` or `NSHTTPCookieOriginURL`.
And value for `NSHTTPCookiePath` should be `@"/"` not `@"\\"`.