# How to insert "Custom cookie" into ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: ios, xcode, cookies, asihttprequest

I got a problem on using ASIHTTPRequest to connect with a site which need me to send a "Custom Cookie" for check.

Firstly, I was googled sometimes and found someway, however, the solution most like to store the cookies as the original "keys", such like "domain", "value" and so on.

My question is, if I would like to set a "Custom Cookie Key" in it, how to make it?

For example, I would like to set a "ServerId" into the cookie as a "key", what can I do?

Well, I had used the following ways but they did not work.

```
NSDictionary *properties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[properties setValue:@"serveridvalue" forKey:@"serveridKey"];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [[NSHTTPCookie alloc]initWithProperties:properties];

[request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[request setRequestcookies:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:cookie]];//BTW, I got a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION here
[request startSynchronous];
```

And here's my other try:

```
NSString *cookie = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"serverid=%@", serverid];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Cookie" value:cookie];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Waiting for your help, guys.

PS: the "request" was created like:

`ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];`

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you solved this, but you're probably getting the "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" because your cookie is probably nil and youre trying to init a array and then add that to the request. There are certain fields that need included for the cookie to initialize properly. Check out this post.

[Create a cookie for NSURLRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691761/create-a-cookie-for-nsurlrequest)